# Sort SparseArray in Android

Tags: android

How can I sort [android.util.SparseArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html)?
E.g. I have SparseArray with:
1 - 2.33
5 - 1.5
Result:
5 - 1.5
1 - 2.33

Thanks!!!

-- EDITED

I've used the Map. Thanks for help.

Comment: Why would you want to sort it? The keys do not change and `SparseArray` does not implement `Iterable`.

Comment: The `Iterable` isn't so much the issue, but I would agree that if the goal is to have this data structure sorted, common Java data structures like a subclass of `Map` would make more sense. Not to say that you couldn't sort a `SpareArray` a desired way, but it's more work than using an out-of-the-box solution.

Comment: @Tom: Yes, he should use another data structure. Even when he manages to sort the `SparseArray` he will not be able to get the values in the right order from it.

Comment: @rocknow regarding your edit: `Map` is just an interface without a contract to sort this. Probably you mean `TreeMap`?

Answer (score 7):

It is not clear if you requested a key or value sorted order ...

so just a note:

A binary search only works on sorted data and SparseArray uses a binary search for its sorted (!) keys array according to [the source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-sdk-4.0.3_r1/core/java/android/util/SparseArray.java#L336). So the keys ARE already sorted and won't accept a different order like the order from the values.

Answer (score 3):

One small amendment to @Karussell's spot-on answer is that also the documentation itself of the [`valueAt()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html#valueAt(int)) method suggests a sorted order (on keys):

> [...] `valueAt(0)` will return the value associated with the smallest key and `valueAt(size()-1)` will return the value associated with the largest key.

A similar description is given for the [`keyAt()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html#keyAt(int)) method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TreeMap. It keeps entries sorted by their key (the key must implement Comparable).

Comment: I would argue this answer is wrong. `LinkedHashMap`s aren't by themselves sorted, nether on key nor on value. According to [JavaSE 7 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) the only guarantee given is to keep the iteration order of the keys: "[...] normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order)". It says nothing about sorting the data (or keys).

Comment: What Shayan_Aryan probably mean is the standard TreeMap or something like ConcurrentSkipListMap, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.html

Comment: @Karussell yes, thanks. I exactly meant that. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the underlying source code for [SparseArray.java](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/1.0/frameworks/base/core/java/android/util/SparseArray.java), you won't be able to do that simply by calling a method. All a `SpareArray` is is two Java-language arrays, one of type `int` and one of type `Object`. Those array's are private instance variables and you cannot reference them without Reflection (which is dangerous as their names may change). A good solution might be to localize the `SpareArray` code in your application and add a `sort` method using normal Java techniques, i.e. [Array.sort](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/arrays/70sorting.html).

Answer (score -1):

**Updated:**

```
private SparseIntArray void sortMap(SparseIntArray unsorted) {
    SparseIntArray sortedSparseIntArray = new SparseIntArray();
    while (unsorted.size() > 0) {
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int minIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < unsorted.size(); i++) {
            if (unsorted.keyAt(i) <= min) {
                min = unsorted.keyAt(i);
                minIndex = i;
            }
        }
        sortedSparseIntArray.put(min, unsorted.get(min));
        sFactorsMap.removeAt(minIndex);
    }
    return sortedSparseIntArray;
}
```

Answer (score -5):

Collect your keys/values to a lists.

```
                List<Integer>keys = Lists.newArrayList();
                List<Integer>vals = Lists.newArrayList();
    SparseArray<Integer>arr;
    for(int i =0; i < arr.size();i++){
    keys.add(arr.keyAt(i));
    values.add(arr.valueAt(i));
    }
    Collections.sort(keys);// sort
    Collections.sort(vals); 
    // then fill your array again.
    arr.clear();
    //...
    arr.put()
```

Comment: That's definitely a valid approach but is dangerous from a performance standpoint. You are creating Lists that don't need to be created and calling a method simply to obtain an array item. Also, size is a method not a field.

Comment: This will definitely mess up the mapping of keys and values.