# Whats efficient way to sort a SparseArray by its keys?

Tags: android, sparse-matrix

I'm using SparseArray to replace need of HashMap considering that it is memory efficient. But I can't see any similar sorting method for SparseArray like Collections.sort . How can i sort it without effecting performance?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort SparseArray in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12157807/sort-sparsearray-in-android)

Comment: I already saw that but didn't get idea from it. As per answer there the keys are already sorted by default but its not showing that way in my list.