# Get selected checklist item expanding ListView Android

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I've been following this logic:  [A multiple choice list view using expansible list](https://github.com/jiahaoliuliu/ExpandableListViewWithChoice)

and managed to create a set of checkboxes in an expandinglistview.

So it looks something like:

```
    catList = new ArrayList<GroupHead>();
    countries = new ArrayList<Country>();
    //Read the XML string
    //Break down the XML into parts

    try 
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builders = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builders.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(XMLResult)));  

        //optional, but recommended
        //read this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786607/normalization-in-dom-parsing-with-java-how-does-it-work
        document.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        String rootNode = document.getDocumentElement().getNodeName().toString();

        if (rootNode.equals("Results"))
        {
            NodeList nList = document.getElementsByTagName("Result");

            System.out.println("----------------------------");

            GroupHead cat1 = null;
            List<GroupSession> result = new ArrayList<GroupSession>();

            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) 
            {

                NodeList TaskTopic = null;
                Element day = (Element) nList.item(temp);
                String Days = day.getAttribute("Day");

                //Add one header (being the PracticalTopic)
                cat1 = createCategory(Days);

                TaskTopic = day.getElementsByTagName("Session");
                for (int j = 0; j < TaskTopic.getLength(); ++j)
                {
                    Element option = (Element) TaskTopic.item(j);
                    String optionText = option.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                    //Add multiple items and set them to that list 

                    String[] results = optionText.split(", ");
                    String StartTimes = results[0];
                    String Lab = results[1];

                    sessions = new ArrayList<String>
                    (Arrays.asList(optionText));

                    ArrayList<String> citiesAustralia = new ArrayList<String>(
                            Arrays.asList(optionText));

                        countries.add(new Country(Days, citiesAustralia));


                    GroupSession item = new GroupSession(StartTimes, Lab);
                    result.add(item);
                    cat1.setItemList(result);
                }
              //Add them to the arrayList
                catList.add(cat1);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.getMessage();
    }
}
else
{
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There are no group sessions available for you", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
}

adapter = new CountryAdapter(this, countries);

expListView.setAdapter(adapter);

// The choice mode has been moved from list view to adapter in order
// to not extend the class ExpansibleListView
adapter.setChoiceMode(CountryAdapter.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

// Handle the click when the user clicks an any child
expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() 
{

    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
            int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) 
    {
        adapter.setClicked(groupPosition, childPosition);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Now what I'd like to do is click a button and return all the selected item values. I have something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) 
{
    int position = checked.keyAt(i);
    if (checked.valueAt(i) != null)
        selectedItems.add(checked.valueAt(i));
}
```

but it's not allowing me to add the `checked.valueAt(i)`. I just want to be able to read all the values from the checked list, but not finding anything that can help.

My adapter is the adapter taken from the example (way too long to add in here)

Please help!

Comment: I'm assuming that FOR block was placed somewhere in the CountryAdapter? Can you show how you declared the `checked` variable and `selectedItems` variable? I'm only seeing a `checkedPositions` variable in that adapter.

Answer (score 1):

```
int key = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
   key = checked.keyAt(i);
   selectedItems.add(checked.valueAt(key));
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8006994/4193263

Comment: Instead of copying an answer directly from another question, you should have marked this question as a duplicate.