# When click on expandable ListView then checked Checkbox is automatically unchecked and Last CheckBox is checked

Tags: android, expandablelistview

[Screnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9O7wj.png) of When I checked first three `CheckBoxes` from `ExpandableListView` and expand first or second Item from it Then second `CheckBox` is automatically **unchecked** and last `CheckBox` is automatically **Checked**

Here is the [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aRo1.png) of it.

Here is my Custom adapter code

```
public class MyBaseExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{
Context context;
ArrayList<Group_Items> group_al;

public MyBaseExpandableListAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Group_Items> group_al) {
    this.context=context;
    this.group_al=group_al;
}
@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    ArrayList<Child_Items> chList = group_al.get(groupPosition).getItems();

    return chList.get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {

    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView,
                         ViewGroup parent) {
    Child_Items ch = (Child_Items) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_child_items, null);
    }
    TextView child = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.child);
    TextView dd = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dd);
    TextView date= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);

    child.setText(ch.getChild_title().toString());
    dd.setText(ch.getDd().toString());
    date.setText(ch.getDate().toString());

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    ArrayList<Child_Items> chList = group_al.get(groupPosition).getItems();

    return chList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {

    return group_al.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {

    return group_al.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {

    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Group_Items gr = (Group_Items) getGroup(groupPosition);
    long group_id = getGroupId(groupPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.expandable_group_items, null);
    }

    TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText(gr.getName());
    CheckBox chk=(CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chk);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {

    return false;
}

}
```

Comment: have you store checked value in Group_Items pogo class?

Comment: Since views get recycled, you need to manually maintain the positions you ticked and update it every time when the getChildView method is called

Comment: @user3676184 I not store any values

Comment: @MuchOverflow can you tell me how I maintain the position??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SparseBooleanArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseBooleanArray.html) for this

in your adapter, initialize and keep a sparse boolean array

```
SparseBooleanArray mSelections = new SparseBooleanArray();
```

in your `getGroupView`, do the following

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, 
                                   View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Group_Items gr = (Group_Items) getGroup(groupPosition);
    long group_id = getGroupId(groupPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.expandable_group_items, null);
       // adding onClick listener on CheckBox for the very first time
       CheckBox chk=(CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chk);
       chk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = (int) v.getTag();
                mSelections.put(position, !mSelections.get(position, false));
                ((CheckBox)v).setChecked(mSelections.get(position, false));
            }

       });
    }

    TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText(gr.getName());
    CheckBox chk=(CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chk);
    chk.setTag(groupPosition);
    // reassigning checkbox to its ticked state
    chk.setChecked(mSelections.get(groupPosition, false));

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: I will check your answer

Comment: I implement your code The problem is that when i click on Expandable list then it says Your application is _Unfortunately Stopped_ insted of expanding

Comment: could you post your stack trace?

Comment: I posted my stack trace you can check it

Comment: ok ok I got my mistake but their is another problem when I check My first CheckBox then Automatically last checkBox is checked

Comment: I have made an edit to my answer. Please check if it works for you. Make sure that the groupPosition variable passed in to getGroupView is not final

Comment: If I remove _final_ from `groupPosition` Then it gives error

Comment: Copy paste the entire method and it should work fine. I have removed usage of groupPosition inside anonymous class so you should not get that error!

Comment: You can get my [sample app from mydrive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By4AGgMQHRz0ZWV4VlJ1UUxGNWM/view?usp=sharing) and check its working    _Now also I facing same problem_

Comment: I do not have permission to access that link

Comment: ohh sorry Please check [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By4AGgMQHRz0ZWV4VlJ1UUxGNWM/view?usp=docslist_api)

Comment: Not sure why this is happening. I suspect it has something to do with the onClickListener. I have made a small update. Could you try that now?

Comment: I have edited the onClickListener of the checkbox. Can you try that please?

Comment: Thank you very much You saved me bro **Its Work Fine** but I have another query .. How to store checked `CheckBox` value in `database`.. I want to store only value of _title_ and _date_ textview of checked `CheckBox`

Comment: That's great! Please accept this as answer if it helped you and for your other problem, please create a new question with detailed description so that others also could answer. You may have to learn to use SQLite for your next problem :)

Comment: yes I will post new question but I want to store value in server side database not in SQLite, I want only hint where I should write code for store that values

Comment: For that you need to publish a REST service on a server and access it from your app to store data. You can use Retrofit library for this purpose. It is fairly easy to do it if you have prior experience in developing web based data systems

Comment: no no I just have only query about from where I can get checked values and send it to db

Comment: You can loop through the SparseBooleanArray and fin out which positions have been marked true. Then use that position to access your grooup_item object in the main ArrayList. Refer this for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8006994/3533289

Comment: sir Can I get Checked `checkbox` values from using `if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()){ }` code in `getGroupView`??  inside the `onClickListener` of `checkBox`

Comment: That would add additional complexity to your code. Since you are mapping checked items in the SparseBooleanArray, you can use that to loop through and identify checked items. Do check the link I posted above on how to do it