# Android app stop working after screen rotation

Tags: android, google-vision

Currently I am using Google Mobile Vision API to do face detection. Supposingly, after the screen rotated, the activity will be restart and all the variables will be reinitialised. However, I dun know why the app stop working and show NullPointerException. Here is my codes.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView mIvDetected;
    private Bitmap mImage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mIvDetected = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_detected);

        //Load an image
        BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opts.inMutable = true;
        mImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.face2);

        //Configure FaceDetector
        FaceDetector detector = new FaceDetector.Builder(this)
                .setMode(FaceDetector.ACCURATE_MODE)
                .setLandmarkType(FaceDetector.ALL_LANDMARKS)
                .setClassificationType(FaceDetector.ALL_CLASSIFICATIONS)
                .setTrackingEnabled(false)
                .build();

        if(false == detector.isOperational()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Face detection service is not ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        //Add the image on a Frame object
        Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(mImage).build();

        //Detect all faces from Frame object
        SparseArray<Face> faceArray = detector.detect(frame);

        //Do some drawing on faces
        **Bitmap outBitmap = drawOnFace(faceArray);**
        mIvDetected.setImageBitmap(outBitmap);

        //Releasing the detector object
        detector.release();
    }

    /** Method to do some drawing on faces */
    private Bitmap drawOnFace(SparseArray<Face> faceArray){

        Paint mIdPaint = new Paint();
        mIdPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        mIdPaint.setTextSize(40.f);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        Paint mTextPaint = new Paint();
        mTextPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mTextPaint.setDither(true);
        mTextPaint.setTextSize(20);
        mTextPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        mTextPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        // Create a blank bitmap same size with the source image
        Bitmap outBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mImage.getWidth(), mImage.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

        // Put the bitmap on canvas for drawing
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(outBitmap);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mImage, 0, 0, null);

        for(int i=0; i < faceArray.size(); i++){
            Face face = faceArray.get(i);

            //Drawing rectangle on each face
            **drawRectangle(canvas, face.getPosition(), face.getWidth(), face.getHeight());**

            //Drawing a point on each face features
            for(Landmark landmark : face.getLandmarks()) {
                switch (landmark.getType()){
                    case Landmark.LEFT_EYE:
                        drawPoint(canvas, landmark.getPosition());
                        canvas.drawText("Left eye: " + face.getIsLeftEyeOpenProbability(), landmark.getPosition().x, landmark.getPosition().y - 30, mTextPaint);
                        break;
                    case Landmark.RIGHT_EYE:
                        drawPoint(canvas, landmark.getPosition());
                        canvas.drawText("Right eye: " + face.getIsRightEyeOpenProbability(), landmark.getPosition().x, landmark.getPosition().y - 30, mTextPaint);
                        break;
                    case Landmark.BOTTOM_MOUTH:
                        drawPoint(canvas, landmark.getPosition());
                        canvas.drawText("Smile: " + face.getIsSmilingProbability(), landmark.getPosition().x, landmark.getPosition().y + 40, mTextPaint);
                        break;
                    case Landmark.LEFT_MOUTH:
                        drawPoint(canvas, landmark.getPosition());
                        break;
                    case Landmark.RIGHT_MOUTH:
                        drawPoint(canvas, landmark.getPosition());
                        break;
                    case Landmark.NOSE_BASE:
                        drawPoint(canvas, landmark.getPosition());
                        break;
                    case Landmark.LEFT_CHEEK:
                        drawPoint(canvas, landmark.getPosition());
                        break;
                    case Landmark.RIGHT_CHEEK:
                        drawPoint(canvas, landmark.getPosition());
                        break;
                    case Landmark.LEFT_EAR:
                        drawPoint(canvas, landmark.getPosition());
                        break;
                    case Landmark.LEFT_EAR_TIP:
                        drawPoint(canvas, landmark.getPosition());
                        break;
                    case Landmark.RIGHT_EAR:
                        drawPoint(canvas, landmark.getPosition());
                        break;
                    case Landmark.RIGHT_EAR_TIP:
                        drawPoint(canvas, landmark.getPosition());
                        break;
                }
            }

            /** Other useful details that may be of your interest */
            Log.d("", "FaceDetection- FaceId:" + face.getId()
                    + " Smiling:" + face.getIsSmilingProbability()
                    + " LeftEyeOpen:" + face.getIsLeftEyeOpenProbability()
                    + " RightEyeOpen:" + face.getIsRightEyeOpenProbability());


        }

        return outBitmap;
    }

    /** This method draws a rectangle */
    private void drawRectangle(Canvas canvas, PointF point, float width, float height){
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        float x1 = point.x;
        float y1 = point.y;
        float x2 = x1 + width;
        float y2 = y1 + height;

        RectF rect = new RectF(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
    }

    /** This method draws a point with hole */
    private void drawPoint(Canvas canvas, PointF point){
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(48);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        float x = point.x;
        float y = point.y;

        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 1, paint);
    }
}
```

Here are my errors.

> 04-24 12:59:50.231 2865-2865/com.example.andy318.cameraone E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                Process: com.example.andy318.cameraone, PID: 2865
>                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.andy318.cameraone/com.example.andy318.cameraone.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.PointF com.google.android.gms.vision.face.Face.getPosition()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3103)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3134)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4077)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1350)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.PointF com.google.android.gms.vision.face.Face.getPosition()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                    at com.example.andy318.cameraone.MainActivity.drawOnFace(MainActivity.java:106)
>                                                                                    at com.example.andy318.cameraone.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:69)
>                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1258)
>                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6312)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3092)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3134) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4077) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1350) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Errors occur on

> Bitmap outBitmap = drawOnFace(faceArray);

and

> drawRectangle(canvas, face.getPosition(), face.getWidth(), face.getHeight());

which I put ** in the coding.

I know where is my error but I dun know how to solve it. After the screen rotated, the SparseArray faceArray have null value. I tried to use if to check null condition but it would not show the detection. (Only show the original picture)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You are only getting the key, not the object: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8006994/6247492

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only getting the key, not the object:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8006994/6247492

Use this code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < faceArray.size(); i++) {
   int key = faceArray.keyAt(i);
   // get the object by the key.
   Face face = faceArray.get(key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'Face.getPosition()' on a null object reference

your face variable is null!

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.html

where do you get detect() from? nvm, found it:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/face/FaceDetector.html#public-methods

Maybe you need to make the SparseArray final or all the faces inside or something like that?